# Is there a generic Android equivalent of Samsung Kies or Nokia PC Suite that works on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, android, desktop-client, synchronization

Is there a generic Android equivalent of Samsung Kies or Nokia PC Suite that works on both Windows and Linux?

I am looking for an utility that allow me to read and send SMS messages, synchronize contacts, transfer files, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) lets you send files, read and send messages, mirror your notifications via wifi. You could also read contacts, drop apk files and install them on your phone. You could also erase the clipboard or change the clipboard content. Wirelessly, you could access the photos, videos in your phone and you can download them. You can operate Airdroid through browser URL or, [Google Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/airdroid/hkgndiocipalkpejnpafdbdlfdjihomd) or as a [Desktop Client](http://dl.airdroid.com/AirDroid_Desktop_Client_3.2.0.exe) or for [Mac OS Client](http://dl.airdroid.com/AirDroid_Desktop_Client_3.2.0.dmg). So you can sync your mobile using a browser in any operating system, but as a standalone client only for Windows and Mac OS.

[image: Sample picture of airdroid working on web through URL]